# c++ List of Struct pop_back Error

Tags: c++, list, struct

I recently have some troubles when I used List with pop_back().

First of all, I defined my struct as follows:

```
struct Pareto{
    double PCost;
    double PDist;
    double DMax,DMin,DAvg,DStd;
    Pareto(double pCost, double pDist, double dMax, double dMin, double dAvg, double dStd){
        PCost = pCost;
        PDist = pDist;
        DMax=dMax;
        DMin = dMin;
        DAvg = dAvg;
        DStd= dStd;
    }
};
```

And then I made a list of Struct as shown below.

```
list<Pareto> ParetoSet;
```

Strangely, there is no error when I use push_back, but when I use pop_back, the following error occurs.

```
ParetoSet.pop_back();
```

Error LNK2019 & LNK1120

"public: class std::list >::_Const_iterator<1> & __thiscall std::list >::_Const_iterator<1>::operator--(void)" (??F?$_Const_iterator@$00@?$list@UPareto@@V?$allocator@UPareto@@@std@@@std@@QAEAAV012@XZ) function

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the full error messages?

Comment: 1>ex.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: class std::list<struct Pareto,class std::allocator<struct Pareto> >::_Const_iterator<1> & __thiscall std::list<struct Pareto,class std::allocator<struct Pareto> >::_Const_iterator<1>::operator--(void)" (??F?$_Const_iterator@$00@?$list@UPareto@@V?$allocator@UPareto@@@std@@@std@@QAEAAV012@XZ)
1>"filepath" : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce your problem.
Could you run this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Pareto{
    double PCost;
    double PDist;
    double DMax,DMin,DAvg,DStd;
    Pareto(double pCost, double pDist, double dMax, double dMin, double dAvg, double dStd){
        PCost = pCost;
        PDist = pDist;
        DMax=dMax;
        DMin = dMin;
        DAvg = dAvg;
        DStd= dStd;
    }

};


ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Pareto& p) {
    out << "PCost: " << p.PCost << ", PDist: " << p.PDist << ", DMax: " << p.DMax << ", DMin: " << p.DMin << ", DAvg: " << p.DAvg << ", DStd: " << p.DStd;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    list<Pareto> list;
    list.push_back({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    list.push_back({0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50});
    cout << "Initial size: " << list.size() << endl;
    list.pop_back();
    cout << "Size after pop_back: " << list.size() << endl;
    Pareto p = list.back();
    cout << "Left item: " << p;
}
```